# public_path() laravel not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

`public_path()` isn't working for me (local environment works, production returns empty string). All other `path` functions are working correctly (app, base and storage).

I searched on google but not find a solution.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Problem solved. I changed values in bootstrap/paths.php

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe for future reference, you change the default value of public: `"public" => __DIR__."/../public"`  to .. ?

Comment: Was exactly this I did :)

Answer (score 5):

*The OP solved his problem by himself. I'm only posting this answer so it's more visible and the question doesn't show up under "unanswered"*

The configuration value for the public path may needs to be adjusted.

**bootstrap/paths.php**

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can add below code into index.php file in public_html folder in web server.

```
// set the public path to this directory
$app->bind('path.public', function() {
return __DIR__; });
```

Comment: Best solution, but don't forget to make the same in artisan and in server.php (if needed) with correct path.

Answer (score 0):

To update the `public_path()`

**Update `public` in bootstrap/paths.php**

`'public' => __DIR__.'/../your_public_folder_path'`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the Providers/AppServiceProvider.php file and register public_html folder instead of public folder. Here is the code

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;
```

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

```
...

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
      return base_path().'/public_html';
    });
}
```

}