# public path is not working in production but it's work in local

Tags: php, laravel

[image: screenshot]`public_path()` doesn't working for me in production , but in local environment it works.

In localhost `public_path()` function is working fine. But when the files are moved to the server it gives an error

Comment: show your code, se we can help

Answer (score 2):

in Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php you will find:

```
 /**
     * Get the path to the public / web directory.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function publicPath()
    {
        return $this->basePath.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'public';
    }
}
```

while basePath returns The base path for the Laravel installation ....

some times this path doesn't serve as you want, so you have to overwrite it ...
please remember that you can not change this class code because it 's out of your project code ...
you have some choices according to your laravel version:

1- adjust the paths values in bootstrap/paths.php

```
'public' => __DIR__.'/../public'
```

see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27271590/10573560

2 - You can override the public path using ioc container :

```
App::bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path().'/public_html';
});
```

and there is some good suggestion in this discussion on [laracast](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/where-do-you-set-public-directory-laravel-5) it contains very good ideas

Answer (score 1):

you must change the public folder path in `index.php`.
[image: public folder on server]

sometimes this folder is called `public_html`. An example of a typical user `public html` path is `/home/user/public_html`.
so these are the 4 most important files you need to change in order to run your application in a custom public folder:
**./server.php**
This file is in the root folder. Is used by the local PHP development server when you call the command php artisan serve. It has a hard-coded value for the public folder. Change this values to your custom path (Example: `public_html`).

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
  return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

**./app/AppServiceProvider.php**

In this file you can register and start some service providers of the application. There is a function named `register()`. Generally, this section is empty by default. You need to add extra code to define a custom application path.

```
public function register()
{
  $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return base_path().'/public_html';
  });
}
```

**./config/filesystems.php**
This file defines some important filesystem locations, use of cloud filesystems and other file-related configuration. Modify the section `public` to change the `root` value `app/public` to your desired location, for example, `app/public_html` (`app` is an **alias** of your root folder).

```
'public' => [
  'driver' => 'local',
  'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
  'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
  'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

**./webpack.mix.js**

Optionally, some Laravel installations are using the Laravel Mix plugin module to generate unified and minified versions of javascript, css and other front-end files using the Webpack npm plugin. These files are installed in the public folder (for example, `./public/js` and `./public/css/`). Add a line to change the default public path (`mix.config.publicPath`), and change the public folder to your desired **public** folder name in the Laravel mix configuration.

```
mix.config.publicPath='public_html';
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public_html/js')
  .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public_html/css');
```

**Moving your public folder**
The simplest way to move your public folder to another one, is using the move (`mv`) command. After that, your public folder now will be renamed.

```
mv public public_html
```

[refrence](https://developerhowto.com/2018/11/12/how-to-change-the-laravel-public-folder/)